# Visio custom page print with Adobe PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, microsoft-visio

I want to use my Adobe Distiller as the printer for a visio document with many pages, each one of different size.
The issue is that when I print all the pages are A4. I want to automatically have the size cut. I know that I can make a custom paper size and select it, but this is really hard as there are many pages.

Thanks.

Note: I don't want save as PDF from visio as the quality is not enough.

Comment: I found a possible answer at http://www.wikihow.com/Crop-Pages-in-a-PDF-Document. Is there anyway to make that automatically?